# CMake with CUDA: ccbin enclosed with unnecessary quotation marks (\")

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I've set up my CMakeLists.txt so that `${CUDA_HOST_COMPILER}` is `/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc` (which points to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.9`). This is as it should be and has been working fine for me... until today. I ran a build, and during the intermediate link phase, I got:

```
"/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc": No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/tester.dir/build.make:2335: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/wherever/foo_intermediate_link.o' failed
```

On closer inspection, it turns out that the compilation nvcc commands are:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc foo.cu -dc -o CMakeFiles/someplace/foo.cu.o -ccbin /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc -m64 etc. etc.
```

but the intermediate link command is

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 -g -G --generate-line-info -m64 -ccbin \"/usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc\" -dlink etc. etc.
```

Note the escaped `\"`s. Why is this happening?

PS - My prime suspect reason is the effect of an `apt-get upgrade` which might have changed something in the CMake version I have (this is a Debian Stretch machine).

Answer (score 2):

It seems I was right: In `/usr/share/CMake/FindCUDA.cmake`, line 1554, we need to replace:

```
      list(APPEND nvcc_flags -ccbin "\"${CUDA_HOST_COMPILER}\"")
```

with

```
      list(APPEND nvcc_flags -ccbin "${CUDA_HOST_COMPILER}")
```

which doesn't enclose your compiler path with extra quotation marks.